# IOS: Mail application sync functionality implementation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to implement the functionality of IOS mail application mail syncing when the table view scrolls to top the mails starts syncing. I just wanted to know that how can i get the event of table view to start syncing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following two good projects

[`EGOTableViewPullRefresh`](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh)

[`PullToRefresh`](https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh)

Answer (score 0):

That feature is called pull-to-refresh, and that drip looking control is called the UIRefreshControl for iOS6. Here is a random tutorial after a google search: http://www.lextech.com/2012/10/ios-6-pull-to-refresh-tutorial/